# How to change the color of the horizontal line when rows are folded in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When I click on the minus sign to fold rows in Notepad++, the rows are all collapsed and replaced by a single horizontal line.

All sections which contain folded rows then have a single horizontal line indicating that there are folded rows underneath. Can the color of this horizontal line be changed from the default black to a very light grey.

Comment: It has been asked and answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/425831/how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-the-fold-indicator-in-notepad

Comment: Actually, that other question seems to be referring to the vertical line in the margin, to the left of the body of an expanded fold. The OP is asking about the horizontal line below a collapsed fold.

Comment: "way to just get rid of the fold line" https://superuser.com/questions/1518673/how-to-remove-or-hide-the-folding-line-in-notepad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Settings → Style Configurator. From the selection box on the right, choose to edit either "Global Styles" or a particular language of your choice (you probably want Global Styles so it affects Notepad++ at all times). From the second selection box ("Style:"), select "Default Style". From the "Colour Style" box at the right, select a foreground color of your choice.

Comment: That changes the background for my current active line.  I want to change the black line that is indicating all the places where rows are folded.

Comment: @ChrisG. Whoops, sorry, I misread your question. I've edited my answer - you should alter the "Default Style" foreground in the Style Configurator.

Comment: This works but also changes the foreground text color when I'm typing text under some situations (for example, when I type a text literal in quotes).  Is there any way to only change the color of the horizontal fold line without also changing the foreground color for other items?  I want to target the horizontal fold line specifically.

Comment: @ChrisG. Hm. I was worried that might happen. You should be able to work around this by manually configuring the foreground colors for each style for each language you code in (e.g. select "C", and then go through "PREPROCESSOR", "INSTRUCTION WORD", etc and set them all to the right color). Unfortunately, this will probably be time-consuming, and I don't know a better way around this.

Comment: @ChrisG. Having checked all the various styling options, I'm pretty sure that the only way to change the color of the fold line is by changing the Default Style. Which is kind of dumb, but... there you have it. :\

Comment: Thank you so much for digging into this. I've decided to just accept that the text will be light grey when I'm typing in a text literal.  Having the fold line be light grey is much easier to work with.  Thanks again!

Comment: Is there any way to just get rid of the fold line?  With the + to the left, you don't really need it...